# How can I assign a normal table from a dynamic pivot table?

Tags: sql, report, pivot-table, stimulsoft

I need to make a report in Stimulsoft from the last 12 months from our current date, I used dynamic pivot table to make this, the original table is at figure 1

[image: Original table data]

Then the pivot table is like the figure 2 (bigger image link here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPCuP.jpg)

[image: pivot table]

The DACP_Value at figure 1 is the row at the date it corresponds at figure 2. Note that the culture is set to pt-BR (brazil)

Here is a sample code of the generation of the pivot table made in SQLFiddle

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3205a/23

I need to put this dynamic data with the headers inside a normal table (it can be a temporary table) so I can use it in my report query and be recognized by the Stimulsoft software.

Answer (score 3):

Add `INTO YourTable`  after the `SELECT` on your code:

```
DECLARE @Col NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
    (   SELECT  ', ' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - (12 - Number), 0), 103)) + ' = [' + CAST(number AS VARCHAR) + ']'
        FROM    Master..spt_values
        WHERE   Type = 'P'
        AND     number BETWEEN 0 AND 12
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')


DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
        N'WITH Data AS
        (   SELECT  DACP_ID,
                    DACP_Value,
                    [MonthNum] = 12 - DATEDIFF(MONTH, DACP_Date, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
            FROM    yourtable
            WHERE   DATEDIFF(MONTH, DACP_Date, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) BETWEEN 0 AND 12
        )   
        SELECT  DACP_ID' + @Col + '
        INTO YourTable --Add this line here
        FROM    Data
                PIVOT
                (   SUM(DACP_Value)
                    FOR MonthNum IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12])
                ) pvt;'

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
```

Comment: Using INTO YourTable, you can get your data into that table (not a temp table).  You can then use that table in Stimulsoft.  I'd probably just recommend dropping that table before running this.  Here is the Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3205a/34

Comment: Thanks Lamark, but what i am trying to do is to put the @SQL variable into a temp table so I can map all the columns from the dynamic sql into stimulsoft to make the report

Comment: i need to select the columns in stimulsoft, it cannot be done with stored procedures

Answer (score 0):

As a way, you can use the master-detail report in Stimulsoft tool. 
As master table you can use the table with date only:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - (12 - Number), 0), 103) AS DT,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - (12 - Number), 0))) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - (12 - Number), 0))) As MonthYear
  FROM Master..spt_values
 WHERE Type = 'P'
       AND number BETWEEN 0 AND 12
```

The detail table it's "yourTable" with additional column:

```
select *, convert(varchar(2),Month(DACP_date)) + convert(varchar(4),Year(DACP_date)) as MonthYear from yourtable
```

realtion on MonthYear columns.
In report you can use the Cross-Data component for master data, and DataBand component for detail data.
Please see the image from the following link:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfSft.jpg

Comment: can you please upload this .mrt of the image?

Comment: Please check the file from the following link: https://docs.google.com/folder/d/0Bx_--XLaflQ7LVp5NlhiUWhiSU0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Also this is a solution for the case when the amount of data for each date is the same, ie ID for each date are the same. If not, one may have to add more conditions for showing headers on the left side.

Comment: the Id for each date is the same, thanks, waiting for the sample file, i think this is a better solution than using sql itself