# How do I put dynamic SQL into temptable if I don't know what columns headers are going to be created?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, pivot, temp-tables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I assign a normal table from a dynamic pivot table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653278/how-can-i-assign-a-normal-table-from-a-dynamic-pivot-table)

I have this Query:

```
DECLARE @Col NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
    (   SELECT  ', ' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - (12 - Number), 0), 103)) + ' = [' + CAST(number AS VARCHAR) + ']'
        FROM    Master..spt_values
        WHERE   Type = 'P'
        AND     number BETWEEN 0 AND 12
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')



DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
        N'WITH Data AS
        (   SELECT  DACP_Id, DACP_Value, ResultCenters.RSL_CodDescr AS CentroResultado, Users.USR_EmpName Colaborador, Devices.DEV_NoArea+Devices.DEV_No as AreaNumero,
                    [MonthNum] = 12 - DATEDIFF(MONTH, DACP_Date, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
            FROM    DevicesAccompaniments INNER JOIN
                    Devices ON Devices.DEV_Id = DevicesAccompaniments.FK_DEV_Id INNER JOIN
                    ResultCenters ON ResultCenters.RSL_Id = Devices.DEV_RsltId INNER JOIN
                    Contracts ON Contracts.CNT_Id = Devices.DEV_ContrId INNER JOIN
                    Users ON Users.USR_Id = Devices.DEV_UsrId
            WHERE   DATEDIFF(MONTH, DACP_Date, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) BETWEEN 0 AND 12 
        )   
        SELECT  CentroResultado, Colaborador, AreaNumero' + @Col + '
        FROM    Data
                PIVOT
                (   SUM(DACP_Value)
                    FOR MonthNum IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12])
                ) pvt;'
```

It creates 12 columns and additional info about the 12 past months from our current date, the problem is that I need to put this query into a report but I need to map the columns into a temptable with the info inside the var @SQL without only executing 'EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;' Here is a sample fiddle with the past 12 months from current date: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3205a/14

Any help is welcome, thanks.

Comment: How is this different from your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653278/how-can-i-assign-a-normal-table-from-a-dynamic-pivot-table

Comment: i think that question is misconceived, ive already voted to delete it

Comment: Instead of posting a new question, all you need to do is edit it with the new details and changes so it can be answered correctly.  Posting a new version of the question is not the appropriate way to handle it.

Comment: @bluefeet I think that depends. If there were already answers based on the original question, and edits to the question would invalidate those answers, I'd leave the original question and start a new one - makes little difference to the OP but it sure is a better gesture to those who invested time in answering the original question (even if it was wrong).

Answer (score 1):

I have a saved script that generates an insert statement based on the current schema (making it adaptive to future versions of our database). The basic idea on this is it merges data from one table (with a completely different schema, but something I know to have related data) and uses an existing record in the destination table as a template to fill in the missing data.

I do believe this script is a little bit more complicated than what you need. However, I think all the tools you'll need are here to customize it to your needs.

```
DECLARE @SourceID VARCHAR(50), @DestinationID VARCHAR(50), @TemplateID VARCHAR(50)
-- Replace with Source ID which has menus to convert
SELECT @SourceID = '<SCREENID>' 
-- Replace with Destination container ID which will contain the parent record for the new data.
SELECT @DestinationID = '<DestinationID >' 
-- ID of template record will will be used to fill in gaps in data.
SELECT @TemplateID = '<Template Record's ID>'

-- Initialize Cursor to gather schema about destination table.
---- This should make this script schema independent
DECLARE @ColumnBuilder NVARCHAR(4000),@ColumnTemp VARCHAR(50)
select @ColumnBuilder = ''

DECLARE ColumnCursor CURSOR LOCAL
FOR select Column_Name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<DESTINATION TABLE NAME>' ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION

OPEN ColumnCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM ColumnCursor
INTO @ColumnTemp

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

SELECT @ColumnBuilder = @ColumnBuilder + 'C.' + @ColumnTemp + ','

FETCH NEXT FROM ColumnCursor
INTO @ColumnTemp

END
CLOSE ColumnCursor
DEALLOCATE ColumnCursor
-- End Cursor

-- Modify some values, for example, we don't want to copy in the template's PK, instead we'll generate a newid()
SELECT @ColumnBuilder = SUBSTRING(@ColumnBuilder, 1,LEN(@ColumnBuilder)-1) -- get rid of last comma.

SELECT @ColumnBuilder = REPLACE(@ColumnBuilder,'C.TableID,','newid(),')
SELECT @ColumnBuilder = REPLACE(@ColumnBuilder,'C.ParentID,','''' + @DestinationID + ''',')
SELECT @ColumnBuilder = REPLACE(@ColumnBuilder,'C.ColumnINeverWantCopied,','NULL,')
SELECT @ColumnBuilder = REPLACE(@ColumnBuilder,'C.TranslateMe,','MI.TranslateableData,')
SELECT @ColumnBuilder = REPLACE(@ColumnBuilder,'C.Order,','MI.Order + C.Order,')
SELECT @ColumnBuilder = REPLACE(@ColumnBuilder,'C.EntryBy,','''TranslateScript'',')
SELECT @ColumnBuilder = REPLACE(@ColumnBuilder,'C.UpdateBy,','''TranslateScript'',')
SELECT @ColumnBuilder = REPLACE(@ColumnBuilder,'C.EntryDtm,','getdate(),')
SELECT @ColumnBuilder = REPLACE(@ColumnBuilder,'C.UpdateDtm,','getdate(),')

-- Set Label of new buttons
SELECT @ColumnBuilder = REPLACE(@ColumnBuilder,'C.Label,','
CASE WHEN MI.Alias IS NULL
THEN
CASE WHEN MI.CommandID = 7 THEN ''Dial''
WHEN MI.CommandID = 8 THEN ''Email''
ELSE S.Alias
END
ELSE MI.AlternateAlias
END,')

-- Build INSERT statement
SELECT @ColumnBuilder = 'INSERT INTO <Destination table> SELECT ' + @ColumnBuilder + ' from 
(<Source Table> MI LEFT JOIN <Source's Parent Table> S ON MI.ParentID = S.ParentID), <Destination table> C
WHERE MI.ParentID= ''' + @SourceID  + ''' AND C.TableID = ''' + @TemplateID  + ''' 
AND MI.CommandID NOT IN (25,43,32,11,45)'

-- Return whole generated statement, for debugging
SELECT @ColumnBuilder

-- Execute!
exec sp_executesql @ColumnBuilder
```